# Prevent 10.2 from creating "Wolfram Mathematica" directory on Linux

Tags: front-end, linux, version-10.2

Since upgrading to version 10.2.0.0, every time I start the Mathematica front-end it creates a "Wolfram Mathematica" directory under my home directory. (It never seems to put anything in it.) Anybody know how to prevent this behaviour?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The "Wolfram Mathematica" directory is created automatically by the front-end and is located in [`$UserDocumentsDirectory`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$UserDocumentsDirectory.html).

It is the default directory to save new documents in and also is on [`TrustedPath`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NotebookSecurity.html).

The typical location for Linux systems is `$HOME/Documents`, however it may happen to fall back on `$HOME` depending on the [Xdg user directories](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xdg_user_directories) setting. This can be changed by

```
xdg-user-dirs-update --set DOCUMENTS AnyDesiredDirectory
```

which can prevent the home directory cluttering behavior by using another location.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I take it this means I can't prevent it? For now I've just put a RemoveDirectory in my init.m

Comment: @Matt Correct, no way to prevent the *creation* of that directory, but it is possible to change its *location* in case the home directory is objectionable.

Comment: OK. I don't have xdg-user-dirs installed which is why it was defaulting to my home directory. I've created a dummy xdg-user-dir that just echoes "/home/matt/.Mathematica" which keeps the "Wolfram Mathematica" directory out of sight and out of mind.

Comment: Is this the intended behavior? Or is this faulty behavior? I don't really like a "Wolfram Mathematica" directory under my ~/Documents directory.

Comment: @Andreas It is the intended behavior. Personally I think users should have more control over this -- I would recommend sending feedback to support so they can file a formal suggestion on your behalf.

Comment: Hi, I have OS X 10.10 installed, and MMA also create a "Wolfram Mathematica" in my $UserDocumentsDirectory, is there any method like ```xdg-user-dirs-update --set DOCUMENTS AnyDesiredDirectory```?

Comment: @nix On OS X the location is determined by querying for `NSDocumentsDirectory` via the `NSSystemDirectories` API, I am not sure if the operating system allows users to override this in any way.

Comment: @ilian If you don't mind, I would ask a simple question that is "How to query ```NSDocumentsDirectory``` via the ```NSSystemDirectories```?", for I have never done such things before.

Comment: @nix Sorry, that was too vague -- the API is what the FrontEnd code uses to ask the operating system for the user's documents directory. It then uses the value returned by the OS. I don't think there is a way to make this to be a different location on Mac (besides relocating your entire home directory, but you will still get the `~/Documents/Wolfram Mathematica` created no matter where `~` happens to be).

Answer (score 8):

Indeed this is annoying. In my `~/.Mathematica/Kernel/init.m` I have placed this removal code:

```
With[{dir = $UserDocumentsDirectory <> "/Wolfram Mathematica"},
  If[DirectoryQ[dir], DeleteDirectory[dir]]
]
```

Comment: Instead of adding "Documents" manually to the path (if necessary), replace `$HomeDirectory` with `$UserDocumentsDirectory`.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up following the last solution suggested, that is, deleting the folder in the init file. Although it required a few minor modifications for it to work on Windows.

Specifically, Mathematica 11 on Windows 7 creates the folder MyDocuments\Wolfram Mathematica each time it starts, and I couldn't find a user-friendly way to modify or prevent this through the GUI in Preferences, which annoys the hell out of me.

As a simple workaround for Windows, consider editing

C:\ProgramData\Mathematica\Kernel\init.m

adding the command

```
With[{dir = $UserDocumentsDirectory <> "\\Wolfram Mathematica"}, If[DirectoryQ[dir], DeleteDirectory[dir]]]
```

to delete it automatically. Note the DOUBLE backslash as folder separator. Alternatively, use FileNameJoin.

Thanks to Darko Veberic for the suggestion.

Comment: Instead of double (back-)slashes you could also use `FileNameJoin[{$UserDocumentsDirectory, "Wolfram Mathematica"}]`, which would pick the backslash automatically on Windows.