# Changing $UserDocumentDirectory variable

Tags: front-end, files-and-directories, customization

Every time I open Mathematica, it creates a "Wolfram Mathematica" folder in my documents folder. But I keep all my Mathematica stuff in the directory "C:/.../Documents/Code/Wolfram Mathematica". How can I make it so Mathematica recognizes this folder instead, and doesn't continue to create its own folder in Documents?

Comment: You'll have to set it at the OS level to get it to change where that's made. See [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/89371/38205). You can also put something in your `init.m` file that removes this directory.

Comment: I can't find an `init.m`, only a `sysinit.m`. But it is not allowing me to edit this document.

Comment: Possible locations for `init.m` are listed under "Details" in the [documentation for init.m](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/file/init.m.html).  If you don't already have an `init.m`, create one.

Comment: [There may be no way to change this variable.](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2007/May/msg00948.html) I'd expect that the directory is created by the FE, not the kernel, but I have not tested it and cannot test it because I am on Windows (@LouisB)

Comment: Almost a duplicate: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/89369/12  Also: http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/573855 (asked twice but no good solution)